# Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault on Ubuntum16.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, teradata

Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault on Ubuntu 16.06

I am trying to connect to teradata by python on ubuntu but getting segmentation fault error.
Installed latest python3.7.4,Ubuntu 16.04 VM, installed teradata ODBC driver for Ubuntu.

```
import datetime
import teradata
import pandas as pd

udaExec = teradata.UdaExec(appName = 'Test',version='1.0',logConsole=False)
    with udaExec.connect(method=method,system=host,username=username,password=password,driver=driver) as connect:
        query_str = "select * from table;"
        sql_vfid_df = pd.read_sql(query_str,connect)
        return sql_vfid_df

Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Current thread 0x00007f92ff5c9700 (most recent call first):
  File "/home/srinivt/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/teradata/tdodbc.py", line 450 in __init__
  File "/home/srinivt/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/teradata/udaexec.py", line 183 in connect
  File "./tokenization/tok-tr.py", line 51 in query_df_csv
  File "./tokenization/tok-tr.py", line 76 in <module>
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Be sure your search path references the correct version (32-bit or 64-bit) of the ODBC driver, depending on which flavor of Python you are running. (I'm assuming the keyword values have been anonymized in your example; driver=driver won't work, obviously.)

Comment: Thanks for reply, here driver is "Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20", method is "odbc",uid is 'my teradata user name' and provided the password.

Comment: Please find ~.odbc.ini config details

Comment: [ODBC]
InstallDir=/opt/teradata/client/ODBC_64
[ODBC Data Sources]
Teradata ODBC DSN=Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20
[Teradata ODBC DSN]
Description=Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20
Driver=/opt/teradata/client/ODBC_64/lib/libodbc.so
DBCName=simba server
UID=XXXXX
PWD=YYYYY

Comment: If you want to use the odbc.ini info then the connect method should specify DSN= *theDataSourceName* not Driver=. Also libodbc.so is the *driver manager* not the driver. For 16.20 the driver filename is tdataodbc_sbu.so